# Passing ByteArray from flash (as3) to AMFPHP (2.0.1)

Tags: php, json, actionscript-3, arrays, amfphp

i have a problem passing ByteArray from flash (as3) to amfphp to save an image.
With old version of amfphp, all worked in the past… now, with new version i have many problem.
I'm using version 2.0.1 and the first problem is that i have to do this, for access to my info:

```
function SaveAsJPEG($json)
    {
        $string =  json_encode($json);
        $obj = json_decode($string);

        $compressed = $obj->{'compressed'};
    }
```

in the past i wrote only:

```
function SaveAsJPEG($json)
    {
        $compressed = $json['compressed'];
    }
```

Anyway… now i can take all data (if i use " $json['compressed']" i receive an error) but i can't receive my ByteArray data.
From flash i write this:

```
var tempObj:Object = new Object();
tempObj["jpgStream "]=  createBitStream(myBitmmapData);  // return ByteArray
tempObj["compressed"] = false;
tempObj["dir"] = linkToSave;
tempObj["name"] = this.imageName;
```

So.. in my php class i receive all correct info, except "jpgStream" that seems "null".

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you get 'null' because of json_encode/decode. Try using

```
    $data = (array) $json;
    $compressed = $data['compressed'];
```

This may help http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/data-types/